# How to get information without using pyCURL (requests)

Tags: python, curl

I need to implement the following curl:

```
curl -k https://somelinkhere/get_info -d auth_info='{"session_id":"blablablaidhere"}' -d params='{"id":"12345"}'
```

Currently I have the following code. It is working, but not exactly as I need. I need to get json content from the reply, just one parameter.

```
url = 'https://somelinkhere/get_info'
data = {'auth_info':'{"session_id":"blablablaidhere"}', 'params':'{"id":"12345"}'}
response = requests.post(url, data=data)
res = response.content
print res
```

Now it returns

```
'�Z[o�6�+���֖���ې�0�{h�`
                        AK�M�"����o�9�dI���t��@RI<��"�GD�D��.3MDeN��
                                                                           ��hͣw�fY)SW����`0�{��$���L��Zxvww����~�qA��(�u*#��݅Pɣ����Km���' 
etc.
```

What i need is to output

```
res['balance_info']['balance']
```

If i launch cURL (provided above) from a command line, i have the following:

```
{"balance_info":{"enabled":"Y","balance":"0.55000","out_date_format":"MM-DD-YYYY","password":"12345","blocked":"N"
```

But do not know how to get this parameter using python script

Comment: You should use the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) library, which is done for humans!

Comment: How do you obtain "requests" object ?

Comment: It looks like the response is compressed, maybe with gzip. Usually the server should not send a compressed resonse without being asked. You should try to decompress the result yourself with the gzip library.

Comment: I already using 'requests'. requests.post(url, data=data). The thing is i need exact content, which i provided

Answer (score 1):

As in documentation,[content property](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content) gives the binary version of response. 
You'll need to get the decoded version of request using .text then load it as json.

```
response = requests.post(url, data=data)
#load it as json
item = json.loads(response.text)
```

And now you can access your keys as:

```
response['balance_info']['balance']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/):

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.post('https://somelinkhere/get_info',
    data = {"id": "12345"})
```

See also the documentation to [install Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/) on your virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

What you get is a Gziped JSON string.
You have to [decompress](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html) before reading [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). Then you can use the response as a python dict.

Something like `res = json.loads(zlib.decompress(response.content))`

Comment: Thank you very much! A have added 

`response = zlib.decompress(compressed_response.content, 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)` and now it is working.